# How to fix report RDLC isn't working on IIS without Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, report, rdlc

I have report (*.rdlc) on asp.net mvc 5 with nuget: ReportViewerForMvc. I using Visual Studio 2013.

After I publish to IIS but:

- PC have install Visual Studio: report worked.
- PC have not install Visual Studio: report not worked.

I already tried install report runtime on nuget but still not worked.

**How???**

Comment: Does the server definitely have the reports viewer package? Seems like not, because RDLC was bundled with vs 2013 but made optional later. Are you sure you referencing the nuget package version not the version installed by vs 2023? Click the reference and read the path. It should be path\to\your\solution\packages\...\reportviewerblah, not c:\program files\visual studio\... etc

Comment: I try install report viewer runtime from nuget, I see dll in path project root after publish. I try more and research too but still not work so I ask on stackoverflow. For solution just install visual studio 2013 on server, but I don't want install vistual studio 2013 on server.

Comment: On IIS there is one option. Go to Application Pools.Select your Application pool.Then press advance settings.There is one "Identity" property. Select it and change it to custom account option. Then enter credentials of users through which you hosted your reports.Then restart IIS and check for report output.

Comment: To me that would indicate that your IIS isn't using the dll you installed via nuget, it's using the one installed elsewhere (gac? programfiles folder?) when you install visual studio. Are you certain you have removed all references to reportviewer from your project, deleted all DLLs off disk in your project folder, then reinstalled it in all needed places via nuget and checked the references to make sure they point to the nuget version not anything else?